# Arraylist from class to array in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am kind of new to JSP. I have got some PHP experience.

I am trying to find a way to store the arraylist data retrieved from a java class file to an array in jsp.

JSP code:

```
  <c:forEach items="${mybean.status}" var="element">
      <c:out value="${element}" />
  </c:forEach>
```

Can I store the output retrieved from class file to an array in jsp?

I am looking for something like below. Can this be done with jstl?

```
String []s = new String[count];
for(int i=0;i<=count;i++) {
    s[i] = element ;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That sounds pointless. JSP is just to display data, class is where you do that sort of things.

Comment: Read this link it may helpful for you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835061/add-values-to-arraylist-use-jstl

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can.. even you can store it at once with array.. i did this code using jstl + spring MVC and i got a + button (to add rows) and - button to delete the row (with javascript):

```
<c:forEach items="${customer.contacts}" varStatus="i">
<tr>
    <td><form:hidden path="contacts[${i.index}].id" /> <form:input
            path="contacts[${i.index}].desc" type="text" /></td>
    <td><form:input path="contacts[${i.index}].number"
            type="text" /></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btnbg2" id="del">-</button></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

anda when submit it will store all the list in database

Comment: Question is for storing data into array. No need to save into database.